# Program stops and does nothing for no reason

Tags: c

Here is my code. It will take the info from the user fine, but it doesn't call prims! (it doesn't even print the statement before the call..). The issue is, this main() is simply copy-and-pasted from an attempt at this problem using kruskals instead of prims.. the main is unchanged, and it used to work fine, the only difference is prims() is now there. I can't see any reason why the program would just.. stop (and then does nothing. Blinking cursor nothing). What's going on?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define MAX 50

typedef struct graph{
    int vertices;
    int edges;
    int vertex[MAX];
    int edge[MAX][4]; /*[i][0]=i (edge ref) [i][1]=vertex1 [i][2]=vertex2 [i][3]=weight*/
} Graph;

void prims(Graph graph);

int main () {

    Graph* graph=malloc(sizeof *graph);
    printf("Please enter the number of vertices in your graph: ");
    scanf("%i", &graph->vertices);
    printf("\nPlease enter the number of edges in your graph: ");
    scanf("%i", &graph->edges);

    for (int i=0; i<graph->edges; ++i) {
        graph->edge[i][0]=i;
    ensure_valid_input:
        printf("\nPlease enter the vertices connected by edge %i, and its weight: ",i+1);
        scanf("%i %i %i", &graph->edge[i][1], &graph->edge[i][2], &graph->edge[i][3]);
        if (graph->edge[i][1]>graph->vertices || graph->edge[i][2]>graph->vertices || graph->edge[i][1] <= 0 || graph->edge[i][2] <= 0) {
            printf("\nERROR: One of these vertices is invalid; ensure they are both in range 1 - %d\n", graph->vertices);
            goto ensure_valid_input;
        }
    }

    printf("Try to call the function?");

    prims(*graph);

    /*Print result to screen*/

    /*Print result to file*/

    return 0;
}


void prims(Graph graph){

    printf("Function called...");

    /*Initialise sets and test-values*/

    int edges_ordered[graph.edges];
    int used_vertices[graph.vertices];
    int used_edges[graph.vertices-1];
    int least_avail_edge;
    int least_edge_reset;
    int existing_entry;
    int done=1;
    int vertex_present;

    for (int i=0; i<graph.vertices; ++i) {
        if (i=0) {
            used_vertices[i]=0;
        }
        else {
            used_vertices[i]=-1;
        }

    }

    /*Order the edges*/

    for (int i=0; i<graph.edges; ++i) {
        least_avail_edge = least_edge_reset;
        existing_entry = 1;
        for (int j=0; j<graph.edges; ++j) {
            if (graph.edge[j][3]<=graph.edge[least_avail_edge][3]) {
                for (int k=0; k<graph.edges; ++k) {
                    if (edges_ordered[k]==graph.edge[j][0]) {
                        existing_entry=0;
                    }
                }
                if (existing_entry==1) {
                    least_avail_edge=j;
                }
            }
        }
        edges_ordered[i]=least_avail_edge;
    }

    //Diagnotstic Print

    for (int i=0; i<graph.edges; ++i) {
        printf("\n%d) Edge %d, Weight %d\n)", i+1, edges_ordered[i]+1, graph.edge[i][3]);
    }



    /*Continually add next appropriate edge to tree until spanning*/

    while (done!=0) {



        /*Test to see if all vertices are in the tree yet*/
        done=0;
        for (int i=0; i<graph.vertices; ++i) {
            vertex_present=1;
            for (int j=0; j<graph.vertices; ++j) {
                if (graph.vertex[i]==used_vertices[j]) {
                    vertex_present=0;
                }
            }
            if (vertex_present==1) {
                /*Vertex is missing from tree -- not done!*/
                done=1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not the right question to ask to SO, but you should just ask (and learn to use) your debugger. Trace your program and see what it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of problems with this code, but I suspect the culprit is inside your `prims()` function:

```
if (i=0) {
```

I think you mean `==`. You're setting `i` to zero each time through the loop, which causes the loop to never terminate, freezing your program.

Other problems are that `least_edge_reset` is uninitialized, the return value of `malloc` is not cast (depends on the C/C++ version and compiler settings whether you'll get an error or warning for this), and `sizeof *graph` is awkward. Also there's no protection against exceeding the maximum number of edges, etc. etc., but I'll stop there since it's not what you were asking about.

I suspect your `print` statement IS running, but since there is no `\n`, it is being buffered and not displayed on screen right away, and never gets displayed because `prims()` is stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: Some programmers adopt the practice of writing `if (0 == i)` because if you put the number first you'll get an error out of the compiler if you write `=` accidentally instead of `==`. (Common mistake!)

Comment: Or the alternative practice of using a compiler of reasonable quality with reasonable warning settings.

Comment: -Wall is your friend.

Comment: Thanks a lot; this did indeed fix it. Least_edge_reset was uninitialised (which was also a problem) because that was supposed to be defined before that bit of code, and isn't needed to be defined at declaration - though not doing so messed up my code later on obviously. The things to do with malloc.. well, I don't really understand those; this is just a little project for the sake of a one-semester course on C designed as a first exposition to programming for scientific purposes.